# does pthread_join free the heap that is held by the terminated thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I was reading a textbook which says:

`int pthread_join(pthread_t tid, void **thread_return);`

> The pthread_join function blocks until thread tid terminates, assigns the generic `(void *)` pointer returned by the thread routine to the location pointed to by thread_return, and then reaps any memory resources held by the terminated thread.

I'm a litte bit confused about the memory resources held by the terminated thread, it sounds like pthread_join will call `free` implicitly to free the heap memory in the terminated thread, but obvious it is not true,  for example:

```
void *thread(void *arg) {
  char *ret;

  if ((ret = (char*) malloc(20)) == NULL) {       //<------------allocated heap memory
    perror("malloc() error");
    exit(2);
  }
  strcpy(ret, "This is a test");
  pthread_exit(ret);
}

main() {
  pthread_t thid;
  void *ret;

  if (pthread_create(&thid, NULL, thread, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pthread_join(thid, &ret) != 0) {          
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(3);
  }

  printf("thread exited with '%s'\n", ret);
}
```

after `pthread_join` is called, `ret` still points to the allocated heap memory can the string can be printed. so the allocated heap memory in the peer thread has not freed.

So what kind of memory resources held by the terminated thread will be reaped?

Comment: I think it's just referring to the memory used to represent the thread, not memory used by the thread code.

Comment: Also any 'thread local storage' for the thread will be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a thread; typically something somewhere (e.g. maybe library, maybe kernel) needs to allocate a stack for the new thread, create somewhere to store its state (registers, etc) when it's not using a CPU, create somewhere to store meta-data (signal mask, priority, CPU time used, etc), allocate space for its thread local storage, etc. All of these things need to be released; but they're "internal stuff" that your code isn't responsible for (that the library needs to be responsible for).

Things that you do have control of (memory from heap) mostly belong to the process and don't belong to any specific thread; and won't be released when any thread terminates (unless the last thread terminates causing the process to be terminated because it has no threads left).